# How does the usual properties of Hilbert adjoint operator follow from this definition?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Given two hilbert spaces $X,Y$, and a bounded linear $T:X\to Y$, define $S:Y\to X$ by

$$
S=J_{X}^{-1} \circ T' \circ J_Y
$$

Where $T':Y'\to X'$ is given by $T'(y')=y'\circ T$ for $y'\in Y'$ and $J_X ,J_Y$ are canonical isometries between their respective spaces and duals - That is, for example, $J_X(x)(y)=<x,y>$ for $x,y\in X$

Then one can check $<Tx,y>=<x,Sy>$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$, except that I don't see how- could anyone explain it explicitly?

Comment: because of the isomorphism, $X = X',Y = Y'$ and   $S = T'$

Comment: it does make sense to write that in a real Hilbert space : $y(x) = \langle y,x \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle = x(y)$. in complex ones it is the same with some *, something like $y^*(x) = \langle x,y \rangle = (\langle y,x \rangle)^* = x(y^*)$

Comment: What is $y$ and what is $x$? is $y\in X'$ and $x,y\in X$? I don't think I follow you

Comment: your $J_X,J_Y$ are simply syntactic. do you understand this way ?

Comment: No, $J_X$ and $J_Y$ are very different maps, if I'm right you are saying (in my terms) $J_X(x)(y)=<x,y>=<y,x>=J_X(y)(x)$ in real space, but it has nothing to do with $J_Y$

Comment: yes but $J_X$ is also unitary and invertible $X \to X'$ : so that $X= X'$, i.e.  $x$ is in the same time a vector of $X$ and a continuous linear map $X \to \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ . so that once we know $X= X'$, $J_X = Id_X$ (and it reduces to proving that $X=X'$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem )

Comment: Actually, I kind of see what you are saying, but I'm not sure that's enough to show the adjoint relation. But I think I've come up with something: So $<Tx,y>=J_Y(y)(Tx)=J_Y(y)\circ T \circ x$, but $J_Y(y)$ is just an element of $Y'$, so by definition of $T'$, $LHS=T'(J_Y(y))(x)$. But then $RHS=J_X\circ J_X^{-1}\circ T'\circ J_Y (x)= T'(J_y(y))(x)$ by definition of $S$, so they are equal - I guess you were trying to say this in intuitive manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by a straightforward calculation:
For all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \langle x, S(y) \rangle
  &= \langle x, J_X^{-1}(T'(J_Y(y))) \rangle
   = \langle x, J_X^{-1}(T'( \langle y, - \rangle)) \rangle
   = \langle x, J_X^{-1}(\langle y, T(-) \rangle) \rangle \\
  &= \overline{\langle J_X^{-1}(\langle y, T(-) \rangle), x \rangle}
   = \overline{J_X(J_X^{-1}(\langle y, T(-) \rangle))(x)}
   = \overline{\langle y, T(-) \rangle(x)} \\
  &= \overline{\langle y, T(x)}
   = \langle T(x), y \rangle.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is your definition of inner product about linearity in second argument? - otherwise I see how it's done. Thanks

Comment: I use $J_X$ (and $J_Y$ respectivey) in the way it is defined in the question, which assumes linearity in the second argument.